Julia multiple dispatch on Vararg Types
The following code snippet works (Julia 1.10.2).
mytupletype = Tuple{String, Vararg{String}}
f(DBTable::String) = "SELECT * FROM $DBTable"
f(DBTable::String, date::String) = "SELECT * FROM $DBTable where date  = $date"

function connector(a::mytupletype)::String
    # ...
    return f(a...)
    # ...
end

q1 = connector(("my_table",))
q2 = connector(("my_table", "'2024-02-12'"))

However I would want to be able to call (for example):
connector("my_table", "'2024-02-12'")

rather than (as is):
connector(("my_table", "'2024-02-12'"))

The documentation (Types section) mentions Vararg Tuple Types which is what I used. I want to avoid the Tuple. Is there (an easy'ish) way of achieving this?

why isn't mytupletype just Varargs{String}?

Good point. It can be. But It doesn't answer the question as I still have to use a tuple in my method call.

If mytupletype is Varargs{String} then connector("my_table", "'2024-02-12'") works

Blimey yes! Thank you! I think you meant Vararg rather than the plural. Why not post it as the answer?

If mytupletype is Vararg{String}, then connector("my_table", "'2024-02-12'") works.
